# how can i remove certain characters from my rownames?

Tags: r

I want to remove a part of the rownames in my data frame. i want to remove "."and characters after "."    Does anyone know?

```
head(rownames(data))
[1] "ENSG00000000003.15" "ENSG00000000005.6"  "ENSG00000000419.13" "ENSG00000000457.14"
[5] "ENSG00000000460.17" "ENSG00000000938.13"

i wanna change it to 
[1] "ENSG00000000003" "ENSG00000000005"  "ENSG00000000419" "ENSG00000000457"
[5] "ENSG00000000460" "ENSG00000000938"
```

how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
rownames(data) <- sub("\\..*", "", rownames(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
rownames(data) <- unlist(strsplit(rownames(data), split='.',fixed = T))[1]
```

Comment: The answer from @Antreas Stefopoulos suits for more complicated condition and is more flexible while my answer has limitations and the `rownames(data)` has to follow the same format, just like `"**.**"`. So, I prefer his answer.

Comment: The main issue with these approaches is that if the trimmed values represent a number, then he would probably need a rounding before before sub! Lets hope he doesn't need that!

Comment: I could not agree with you any more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have a fixed length. If it is true, then

```
rownames(data) = substr(rownames(data),1,15)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more sophisticated method is this:

```
sub("([^.]+).*", "\\1", rownames(data))
```

Here, we define a capture group using a negative character class that includes any character but the period `.` and, using backreference `\\1`, 'recollect' just the matching series of digits in `sub`'s replacement argument.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `str_split` like this:

```r
library(stringr)
rows <- c("ENSG00000000003.15", "ENSG00000000005.6",  "ENSG00000000419.13", "ENSG00000000457.14", "ENSG00000000460.17", "ENSG00000000938.13")
str_split(rows, "\\.", simplify=T)[,1]
#> [1] "ENSG00000000003" "ENSG00000000005" "ENSG00000000419" "ENSG00000000457"
#> [5] "ENSG00000000460" "ENSG00000000938"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>